# How to open a specific directory by default on start up of Command line?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, shortcut

When I start up command line, I want a specific directory to be opened by default without me having to type a long path.

e.g.
every time I open a terminal I want to be in directory ~/Desktop/foo/bar, so I want the following to happen

```
ctrl+alt+t
-> "terminal opens"
pwd
-> <yourPath>/Desktop/foo/bar
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put this line at the end of your `~/.bashrc` file (or equivalent if you're using a different shell than bash):

```
cd <yourPath>/Desktop/foo/bar
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add a command to the end of your `.bashrc`

```
cd /path/to/dir
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's Ubuntu terminal you can edit your profile, tick run a custom command instead of my shell and make it:

```
sh -c 'cd ~/Documents; exec "${SHELL:-sh}"'
```

What you might also consider if you want to move through directories quickly as bookmarks (almost), check out [zsh](https://ohmyz.sh/) which has a plugin called [warp directory](https://github.com/mfaerevaag/wd) or if you don't want to make the leap to zsh, [warp-drive fork](https://github.com/kigster/warp-dir).